# What is the use of symbolic links in Yocto deploy folder

Tags: yocto, bitbake

The build process writes images out to the Build Directory inside the `tmp/deploy/images/machine/` folder

For every image type (kernel image, rootfs etc), there are symbolic links

For example,

```
bzImage -> bzImage--5.2.32+git0+bb2776d6be_c926964d00-r0-qemux86-64-20200310141839.bin
bzImage--5.2.32+git0+bb2776d6be_c926964d00-r0-qemux86-64-20200310141839.bin
bzImage-qemux86-64.bin -> bzImage--5.2.32+git0+bb2776d6be_c926964d00-r0-qemux86-64-20200310141839.bin
```

Why can't we have a simple bzImage.

I added a change in local.conf file and created a build, and it did delete the old bzImage and replaced it with new image.

What's the benefit of symbolic links.

From Yocto Manual, it says

```
These links might be useful for external scripts that need to obtain the latest version of each file
```

But i didn't understand this point, as it has already deleted the old file, can anyone explain this

Comment: one such usecase would be when there are image post processing commands/scripts which are run immediately after deploying the images. In those scripts it can reliably use the symlink name since that remains same while the image names might change due to timestamps in it.

Comment: what's the benefit of having names with timestamps, instead of just having direct name like bzImage

Comment: one might deploy these images into a OTA server e.g. and keep multiple versions of the images at a time.

Comment: In that case, he has to manually copy the symbolic links each time

Comment: yes but this clearly tells that its not copying an old file or somesuch, because timestamps are always in increasing order.